# Android Studio - App Preview shows the xml layout but when I run the App on Phone nothing shows up

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to make a simple counter to test out what I've learned so far in Android. The xml seems to be right as it shows up just fine on the preview window but I think there is something off with the java as I can not get it on my phone, it is simply blank.

Here is the xml
http://pastebin.com/G6Y4RFMb

Here is the Java
http://pastebin.com/mNmT3bUJ

Thank you for your time. This is my first time posting so if I did anything wrong please let me know.

Comment: Please include the code in your question in addition to the links.

Comment: @Ernest, please, I humble ask for you to please check my answer as the correct one (If you have found the solution there), since I was the first here to address the question. Thank you. I will +1 you for that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is blank because you have not called your xml to work. Use something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myxml);
}
```

Comment: @Ernest please check the answer you think it was helpful to solve your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this to the activity!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.name_of_the_layout_file);
}
```

Maybe you just missed if not, this method is called by the system and is the right place to set up things. One of these things is the aspect of your activity.

P.S.: this is not Javascript, just Java.